# Multiple pipes on a tailed log - last pipe never receives stdin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, posix

I've gotten into an interesting state on Ubuntu. The steps below describe it the best.

With a single pipe, I'm seeing what I expect

```
# In shell A
tail -f foo.log | grep aaa

# In shell B
echo aaa >> foo.log

# Shell A prints out `aaa`
```

But with multiple pipes I'm not seeing anything at all

```
# In shell A
tail -f foo.log | grep aaa | grep bbb

# In shell B
echo aaa bbb >> foo.log

# Nothing ever prints in shell A
```

But it works fine if I'm just echoing.

```
echo 'aaa bbb' | grep aaa | grep bbb
```

This is my attempt to create a minimal reproduction -- I originally encountered the issue trying to tee logs from adb logcat (Android dev tools). I've tried in zsh, bash, and fish as well.

I assumed it has something to do with my inotify watcher limit but bumping it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of buffering in the pipe, which in general doesn't care about lines and can accumulate data.

I think `tail -f` uses line buffering by itself; and the last `grep` writes to the tty, so it also uses line buffering. Therefore your first example works.

But `grep` in the middle is different and you need to adjust its behavior by forcing line buffering or by disabling buffering. The bellow commands will work as you expected.

- If your `grep` supports `--line-buffered` (it does in Ubuntu):

  ```
    tail -f foo.log | grep --line-buffered aaa | grep bbb
  ```
- More generic solutions (they will work with many filters other than `grep`):

  ```
    tail -f foo.log | unbuffer -p grep aaa | grep bbb
    tail -f foo.log | stdbuf -oL grep aaa | grep bbb
    tail -f foo.log | stdbuf -o0 grep aaa | grep bbb
  ```

See `man 1 grep`, `man 1 unbuffer` and `man 1 stdbuf` for details and quirks.

Notes:

- Neither solution is portable (`grep --line-buffered`, `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` are not specified by POSIX).
- If you can do this with `grep --line-buffered` then it should be your choice. There's no point in using extra tools.
- Related question on Unix & Linux SE: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/108618).
- `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` [work in completely different ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97327/108618).
- With `stdbuf`, line buffering (`-oL`) should be preferred over no buffering (`-o0`) here, because

  - it most likely performs better,
  - and other parts of your pipe use line buffering anyway.
- If your last `grep` wrote to yet another file, it would behave like the other `grep`. In such case if you want lines to appear in the final file immediately, then you should also modify the behavior of the last `grep`.
- In `fish`, if `grep` is a wrapper function, you may not get the desired behavior with `--line-buffered`. Use `command grep --line-buffered`. See this question: [Output pipe waits for EOF in `fish`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305262/108618).

---

Side note: `tail foo.log | grep aaa | grep bbb` (i.e. `tail` without `-f`) does not cause the issue because `tail` exits. When `tail` exits, the first `grep` detects EOF, flushes its buffer and exits, then the second `grep` does the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In testing it I got a new piece of information. It actually works just fine in `zsh`, I'm not sure what changed from my last test, but it looks like its only a problem in `fish`, and there the `--line-buffered` switch actually doesn't do anything it seems. This might be a fish question.

Comment: EDIT: I do need the line-buffered options get it working isntantly in zsh as well, my bad. But I can't get that solution to work in fish.

Comment: Ok, this was the solution, thank you. The tricky part was fish's function wrapper around grep: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305261/output-pipe-waits-for-eof-in-fish. If I use grep directly with /bin/grep it works in fish as well. Not sure why they wrapped it.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo Thanks for the feedback. I integrated your observations and the link into my answer.

Comment: Great answer and special thanks for mentioning that `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` do technically totally different things as explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97327/20336 – `unbuffer` doesn't actually change buffering so it could have name like `pretend-connected-to-terminal` to better describe what it actually does.